# How to dynamically return objects based on conditions in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have implemented five to six clustering algorithms. I want to return the objects of clustering algorithms as the user specifies its name in the "cluster" method. For example:-

```
  val kmeans= data.cluster(clusteringAlgo.Kmeans)
```

As the cluster method invoked with Kmeans and matches against the Kmeans, it should return kmeans instance.

```
  def cluster(firstName: ClusteringAlgorithm.Value):???= {  
  algoName = firstName.toString()
  if (ClusteringAlgorithm.KMeans.toString() == algoName) {
    val kmeans = new Kmeans(input)
    Kmeans
  } 
  else if (ClusteringAlgorithm.DBSCAN.toString() == algoName) {
    val dbscan = new DBSCAN(input, epsilon, maxPoints)
    dbscan
  }
  ......
```

I am facing the difficulty in return types since I have different return types in each condition(kmeans,dbscan etc). What should be at ??? in the code. How can we achieve this?

Comment: A simple switch case or if else condition would work... what exactly is your  issue ?

Comment: @BalajiReddy I am facing the difficulty in return type since I have different return types in each condition(kmeans,dbscan etc). What should be at ??? in the code.

Comment: okay . understood.

Answer (score 1):

Here a possibility (use **Higher Order Functions**):

Provide a Map with constructors:

```
val cluster = Map(ClusteringAlgorithm.KMeans -> createKMeans,
ClusteringAlgorithm.DBSCAN -> createDBScan
) 

def createKMeans() = new Kmeans(input)
def createDBScan() = new DBSCAN(input, epsilon, maxPoints)
```

Usage:

```
val kmeans = cluster(ClusteringAlgorithm.KMeans)()
```

Or **Pattern Matching**:

```
def cluster(name: ClusteringAlgorithm.Value) = name match {
 case ClusteringAlgorithm.KMeans => new Kmeans(input)
 case ClusteringAlgorithm.DBSCAN => new DBSCAN(input, epsilon, maxPoints)
}
```

Usage:

```
val kmeans = cluster(ClusteringAlgorithm.KMeans)
```

This function you can also Parameterize, like

```
def cluster[A](name: ClusteringAlgorithm.Value): A = name match {
 case ClusteringAlgorithm.KMeans => new Kmeans(input)
 case ClusteringAlgorithm.DBSCAN => new DBSCAN(input, epsilon, maxPoints)
}

val kmeans = cluster[Kmeans](ClusteringAlgorithm.KMeans)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @pme. Regarding pattern matching, while using 
       val kmeans = cluster(ClusteringAlgorithm.KMeans)
 
Its returning Object as return type. I want KMeans as its return type. I also tried it:  
      def cluster(name: ClusteringAlgorithm.Value) = name match {
      case ClusteringAlgorithm.KMeans => new Kmeans(input).asInstanceof(Kmeans)
      case ClusteringAlgorithm.DBSCAN => new DBSCAN(input, epsilon, 
     maxPoints).asInstanceOf(DBSCAN)
}
  Actually,  I don't want to use as Instance of during the call(val kmeans = cluster(ClusteringAlgorithm.KMeans))

Comment: Does the client know the type it want's?

Answer (score 1):

Another Alternative besides answer from @pme

```
      trait ClusterAlgo {
        //This is just a marker trait/interface. no implementation is required.

      }

      class Kmeans extends ClusterAlgo {
        // your implementation goes here
      }

      class DBSCAN extends ClusterAlgo {
        // your implementation goes here
      }

      class SomeOtherAlgo extends ClusterAlgo {
        // your implementation goes here
      }

      def cluster(firstName: String): ClusterAlgo = {

        if (firstName.equalsIgnoreCase("kmeans")) {
          new Kmeans
        }
        else if (firstName.equalsIgnoreCase("dbscan")) {
          new DBSCAN()
        }
        else {
          new SomeOtherAlgo
        }

      }

//  This is a piece of code at caller. 
  println(cluster("kmeans").isInstanceOf[Kmeans])
```

Comment: @RajjatDadwal wc. Happy to help